# regex certain character can exist or not but nothing after that

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to do a search on a couple of string.

I wanted to check if a certain character, in this case its ":" (without the quote) exist on the strings.

If : does not exist in the string it would still match, but if : exist there should be nothing after that only space and new line will be allowed.

I have this pattern, but it does not seem to work as I want it.

```
(.*)(:?\s*\n*)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `\n` is included in `\s`.

Comment: @vandale if I did not use "?" : would be required right? how can I say that it can exist or not?

Comment: Your pattern will do the wrong thing for several reasons. Most importantly, it can match anywhere in the target string (since you have no ^ or $ anchors); also, even with a trailing ? the .* portion will match ANYTHING, including invalid sequences of characters (colons followed by non-whitespace).

Comment: Do you want to allow an empty string? A string that consists only of whitespace? A string that consists only of a colon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `^[^:]*(:\s*)?$`

Let's break this down a bit:

`^` Starting anchor; without this, the match can restart itself every time it sees another colon, or non-whitespace following a colon.

`[^:]*` Match any number of characters that AREN'T colon characters; this way, if the entire string is non-colon characters, the string is treated as a valid match.

`(:\s*)?` If at any point we **do** see a colon, all following characters must be white space until the end of the string; the grouping parens and following `?` act to make this an all-or-nothing conditional statement.

`$` Ending anchor; without this, the regex won't know that if it sees a colon the following whitespace MUST persist until the end of the string.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. If the : exist it will still accept the string, but if it does exist I want to make sure that there is no other characters/strings after that, there can only have space or newline.

Comment: I assume you want one of two things: either a string with NO colons, or a string with anything (except colons) followed by ONE colon, followed by whitespace or nothing. Is that correct?

Comment: this works..thanks.. why is there a need for this ^[^:]* .... (:\s*)?$  I assume this part means that the end of string can end to a colon/space or not? is that right?

Comment: @mysticfalls I added some explanatory text in the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

here is a pattern which should work

```
/^([^:]*|([^:]*:\s*))$/
```

you can use the pipe to manage alternatives

Comment: Regex branching is global to the scope it's in; in other words (pattern1)|(pattern2) is identical to pattern1|pattern2--which has some implications for your proposed solution: (a) the first branch is missing the trailing `$` anchor (b) the second branch doesn't need the grouping operator (c) the second branch is missing the leading `^` anchor (d) since branch 1 is a subset of branch 2, it makes more sense not to branch, and just make the latter part of branch 2 optional (see my answer to this question).

Comment: You're right. I didn't know about the large range of branching. Thought it was local to the left and right side element (group/class/character).  I'll edit my answer then... keeping my branching alternative, but including your advices

Comment: Better; you still don't need the inner set of parens on the right branch, but it will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is :

```
^[^:]*(|:[\n]*)$
```

^[^:]* => **starts** with anything except :

(|:[\n]*)$ => **ends** either with exactly nothing **OR** ':' followed by line breaks